# Lagrangian with complicated constraints

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I want to minimize the action
$$S[y'(x)]=\int_0^adx \frac{(y')^2}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}$$
subject to constraints
$$
(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\int_0^adx \sqrt{1+(y')^2} = D\\
(2-5)\;\;\;\;\;\;y(0)=y(a)=y'(0)=y'(a)=0
$$

where $D$ is some real distance $D\geq a$, and I am using $y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$

How do I solve this?

---

What I have done so far:

I am finding with standard methods for analyzing Lagrangians, we identify the Lagrangian L,

$$L=\frac{(y')^2}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}$$

so from the typical analysis with Lagrangians,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial (y')}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$$
and we proceed from here.

But the constraint (1) is not accounted for.

I can think to modify the action i.e. use a Lagrange multiplier,

$$S_{new}[y'(x)]=\int_0^adx \frac{(y')^2}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} + \lambda (\int_0^adx \sqrt{1+(y')^2}-D)$$

but I do not see how this helps.

Do you have ideas on how to approach/solve this?

Comment: What did you find with the multiplier? What fails?

Comment: Hi Mondo Duke. The system (v2) looks overconstrained.

Comment: I believe it is overconstrained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how you are trying to minimize the $S_\mathrm{new}$ equation, so apply the E-L equation to what's under the integral sign.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npt6IkyL_f4&ab_channel=FacultyofKhan This video uses the same approach to solve the Catenary problem, another constrained variational calculus example

Comment: To your answer - I know this already. 

To your comment - this is helpful to me in showing the exact approach. For the catenary problem though, the shape is the same regardless of the length. So it is wasteful to include the constraint on the length of the wire, and there are much easier methods to solving it. Clearly I’m not a fan of Khan academy.